# expandoobject in wcf throws exception when trying to access property which is generated from class that is created from the input soap request

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, expandoobject

Hello I have class that is generated from wsdl. This class I received as input parameter in the wcf service method and convert it to XML. Then from this XML I generate ExpandoObject and try to access the properties, but I get this error 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'SessionData'.
That is my code:

```
public class WalletsManagementImplementation:IWalletsManagementPortTypeSOAP
    {
     public Response CreateWallet(Request request)
     {
     request.CreateWalletRequest = new CreateWalletRequestType();
     request.CreateWalletRequest.SessionData = new SessionDataRequestType();  
     request.CreateWalletRequest.WalletData = new WalletBasicType();
     request.CreateWalletRequest.SessionData.WalletId = 3333;
     request.CreateWalletRequest.SessionData.SessionIPAddress = "10.3";
     string xml = ConvertToXml(request);
     var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
     var xDoc = xmlDocument.ToXDocument();
     dynamic expandoObj = new ExpandoObject();
     ExpandoObjectHelper.Parse(expandoObj, xDoc.Root, new List<string>());
     dynamic s = expandoObj.Request.CreateWalletRequest;
     dynamic k = s.SessionData;
     dynamic x = k.PrefLand;
     return new Response();
    }
}

[DebuggerStepThrough()]
[GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel","4.0.0.0")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class Request
{
[MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://host/WalletsManagement", Order = 0)]
public CreateWalletRequestType CreateWalletRequest;

public Request()
{
}

public Request(CreateWalletRequestType CreateWalletRequest)
{
    this.CreateWalletRequest = CreateWalletRequest;
}
}

[GeneratedCode("svcutil", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[DebuggerStepThrough()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(Namespace="http://host/WalletsManagement")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class CreateWalletRequestType
{

private WalletBasicType walletDataField;

private SessionDataRequestType sessionDataField;

[XmlElement(Order=0)]
public WalletBasicType WalletData
{
    get
    {
        return this.walletDataField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.walletDataField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[XmlElement(Order = 1)]
public SessionDataRequestType SessionData
{
    get
    {
        return this.sessionDataField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.sessionDataField = value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. WCF deserializes it into `Request` automatically, but you re-serialize it, convert it to two types of XML then try to convert it to a dynamic object with [this code project code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/461677/creating-a-dynamic-object-from-xml-using-expandoob)? What is wrong with just using the parameter?

Comment: This is not a minimal example. Only CreateWallet is needed. What do you want to achieve and which implementation of ExpandoObjectHelper did you use? Update your question.

Comment: I use this https://www.codeproject.com/articles/461677/creating-a-dynamic-object-from-xml-using-expandoob implementation of ExpandoObjectHelper. Well my intention is that i want to access this properties from class CreateWalletRequestType that has [XmlElement] attribute and I cannot figure it out why it throws exception, because when I am debugging I can expand the class in Dynamic View and see that there is a definition for SessionData.